# How would I toggle my sidebar in another component?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a header component with a mat-toolbar which I have a button that I want to use to toggle my sidenav bar which is in another component. How would I toggle my sidebar in another component?

I want to toggle it below the header component.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adkpkv

I copied my whole project in here but I can't seem to get it to run in stackbitz. It does run locally though.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adkpkv
I fixed the errors in the stackblitz

Comment: You didn't give me any feedback yet, does my answer work for you? If not, I will help you once I know. But if you are happy with my solution please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi L. Guthardt sorry for not getting back to you sooner. I was away for a few days. I am going to try to implement your solution and get back to you today.

Comment: No problem, just message me once you tried implementing it.

Comment: Okay.. I tried right now and running into one issue.. How is the component of the nav bar set up? This is what I have in the html side <mat-sidenav [@sliderState]="toggleService.sideBarState"  >

I injected the service in the constructor like this 
constructor(private service: ToggleService) { }

But a little confused on how to set the method in the sidenav component... @L.Guthardt

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you using [services](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4). The advantages are that they are very easy to get started with and easy to use. Furthermore a service is accessible of every component or even other services, you can toggle the sidebar from as many different components as you want. *If you are familiar with e.g. C#, a service behaves similar to a singleton in C#.*

So you should create a new service, by typing `ng g s toggle` into the Angular CLI.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ToggleService {

    constructor() { }
}
```

---

**Solution 1:**

This is the simpler way without a nice animation. The easiest way to toggle your sidebar component is by placing it already at the correct position, but setting `display: none`. Then you use `ngClass` to set a css class to the sidebar component, depending on a property. Apply this code into the tag of the top most one of your sidebar component.

```
[ngClass]="{'show-sidebar': toggleService.showSidebar}"
```

In order for that to work, you have to create a new css class in the sidebar's css. Add:

```
.show-sidebar { 
    display: block;
}
```

After that you add a property to the service.

```
private _showSidebar = false;
public get showSidebar(): boolean{
    return this._showSidebar;
}
public set showSidebar(v : boolean) {
    this._showSidebar = v;
}
```

Now you inject the service into the sidebar component and assign it to a property to be able to reference the service in your html file. So you can use the bool value of `showSidebar` to toggle the `show-sidebar` css class.

The next thing is just to inject the service into the component where the button is, that you use to toggle the sidebar. After that you add a click event to the button where you change the value of `toggleService.showSidebar` to `true`.

---

**Solution 2:**

Now if you want to use e.g. [Angular Animations](https://angular.io/guide/animations) you can add a property to the service that you can change from one compontent and that change will toggle the animation state to animate your sideBar to move into the screen.

```
private _sideBarState = 'inactive';
public get sideBarState(): string {
    return this._sideBarState;
}
public set sideBarState(v : string) {
    this._sideBarState = v;
}
```

Next you bind a sliderState to your component in html, so in the html of the sidebar component. Just add this into the tag of the top most one in your sidebar.

```
[@sliderState]="toggleService.sideBarState"
```

To be able to do that you have to inject the `toggleService` into your sidebar component before. If you have question about that, just go ahead and ask me.

After that you have to add the different animations in the decorator of the component that you want to animate, the sidebar component.

```
@Component({
selector: 'core-detail-page',
templateUrl: './detail-page.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./detail-page.component.scss'],
animations: [
    trigger('sliderState', [
        state('active', style({
            left: '0',
            display: 'block'
        })),
        state('inactive', style({
            left: '-300px',
            display: 'none'
        })),
        transition('inactive => active', animate('300ms ease-out')),
        transition('active => inactive', animate('300ms ease-out'))
    ])
]
```

})

Those are just some dummy values where I pretend that your sidebar component is set to `position: absoulte` and placed right next to your screen, those `-300px`. And once you change the value of the `sidebarState` in the `toggleService` to `active` the property `left` and `display` will be animated due to your defintions of the animation. You can animate any property you want.

Changing the `sidebarState` is done by injecting the `toggleService` into the component where your button, which you want to use to toggle the sidebar, is located. After injecting the service, you add a click method to the button and in this method you change the value of `sidebarState`.

```
toggleSidebar() {
    this.toggleService.sideBarState = 'active';
}
```

Comment: @elquesogrand  If you have any question or don't understand something, just tell me. :)

Comment: Wow what a super detailed answer, I love it. I will implement services in our project immediately. Sounds like a great way to create different animations and to toggle them.

Comment: @JakubMaleček Again you, that's funny. Glad I could help you out again. If you need some help with the sevices you can hit me up at my mail, is referenced in my profile.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. I will message you there once I step upon errors.

Answer (score 0):

You gotta make a few changes (below) to your existing [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-adkpkv) which will

- take each click (of burger menu) out from `header.component`
- receive this value inside `app.component` (parent) and pass to child
- handle this click in `side-nav.component` (child)

Make these changes & see the toggle reaching from one component to the other... I have added a `<mark>` tag inside the child to check that the value is indeed received there.

change your **header.component.ts** to be like:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() menuState = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }
  opened: boolean;
  showMenu = false; /* false by default, since hidden */
  toggleMenu() {
      console.log("inside toggleMenu");
      this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
      this.menuState.emit(this.showMenu);
   }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

your **header.component.html** to be:

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
        <a href="" class="site-logo">
            <h2>TEST APP</h2>
        </a>
        <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggleMenu()"> 
              <mat-icon>menu </mat-icon>
          </button>
      <span class="example-spacer"></span>
      <mat-icon class="example-icon"  matBadge="15" matTooltip="Recent changes">notifications</mat-icon>
      <mat-icon class="example-icon"  matTooltip="Info or how to contact us">help</mat-icon>
      <mat-icon class="example-icon"  matTooltip="Your account information"> account_circle</mat-icon>
    </mat-toolbar-row>

</mat-toolbar>
```

your **app.component.ts** to be:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'This is the copy of the Expense App';
  subMenuState:boolean = false;
  burgerClicked(evnt){
    this.subMenuState = evnt;
    console.log("inside burgerClicked: pls. change showMenu to be:",this.subMenuState);
  }

}
```

your **app.component.html** to be:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<app-header (menuState)='burgerClicked($event)'></app-header>
<app-side-nav [subMenuState]="subMenuState"></app-side-nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

your **side-nav.component.ts** to be

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-side-nav',
  templateUrl: './side-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./side-nav.component.css']
})
export class SideNavComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() subMenuState;
  constructor() { }
  opened: boolean;
  showMenu = true;
  toggleMenu() {
      this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
   }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(){
    console.log("inside ngOnChanges with subMenuState: ",this.subMenuState );
    this.showMenu = this.subMenuState;
  }

}
```

in your **side-nav.component.html**, I added a row at the top to ensure that value is toggling correctly

```
<mark> Show menu (inside side-nav.component) ? {{showMenu}} </mark>
<mat-sidenav-container >
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side"  mat-disable-backdrop #start >
      <mat-nav-list>
          <a mat-list-item routerLink="/">  
              <mat-icon> home</mat-icon>
              <span> All Reports </span>
          </a>
          <a mat-list-item routerLink="/entries">  
              <mat-icon>  assignment </mat-icon>
              <span> Reports Per Business </span>
          </a>
          <a mat-list-item (click)="toggleMenu()">
                  <mat-icon mat-list-icon>business</mat-icon>Maintenance
                  <mat-icon *ngIf="!showMenu">chevron_right</mat-icon>
                  <mat-icon *ngIf="showMenu">expand_more</mat-icon>
                </a>
                <mat-nav-list class="sidenav-submenu" *ngIf="showMenu">
                  <a mat-list-item  routerLink="/new-entry"> New Report</a>
                  <a mat-list-item > New User</a>
                  <a mat-list-item > New Business</a>
                </mat-nav-list>
                <a mat-list-item >  
                      <mat-icon> account_circle</mat-icon>
                      <span> Login </span>
                  </a>
      </mat-nav-list>

  </mat-sidenav>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem few weeks back and I came across this article that helped me alot. Its explaining how components communicate by toggling a sidebar :)

https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb

Cheers!